# Pass UISegmentControl selectedSegmentIndex to Popover

Tags: iphone

Sorry for the noob question.  I have a view that has a UISegmentControl in the UIToolBar.  I also present a popover from a button.  How do I get the value of the UISegmentControl to the popover?  Should I have the Popover have an NSInteger ivar to hold this value so when I present the popover, I set that value to whatever the selectedSegmentIndex is?  I didn't know if that was the cleanest way since I'm new at this and keep reading stuff about not coupling your classes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , You can use `UIControlEventValueChanged` Event of `UISegmentControl` to directly set the TAG Propertly of popover to the `selectedSegmentIndex` of `UISegmentControl` .

```
{
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(setvalueofselected:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(IBAction)setvalueofselected:(id)sender
{
  popover.tag = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

OR

   self.intSelected = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
}
```

And from with in your popover click event code try to check the property of TAG . You can also use Some Global Integar for this purpose instead of tag property.

In this way your POPOver can know which segment was selected when they clicked popover.